# Is there a way to move all the extra files into a folder?

Tags: c#

Let's suppose I've just compiled my app called "rainbow" (WindowsFormsApp). I'd get the usual "rainbow.exe", "rainbow.exe.config", and also all of the references I used inside the project, like extra DLLs. Is there any way that I can keep the rainbow.exe in a folder, but have all the other files like the references and .config files inside another folder?
For example:

```
folder\rainbow.exe
folder\extra\rainbow.exe.config
folder\extra\rainbow.dll
folder\extra\something.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it is QUITE complex because - the references are there to be loaded and if you move them into another folder.... you must interfere with the .NET runtime.

For the folder part: WRITE A SCRIPT - put it into a post build step, done. The app will stop working.

This is how ALL windows applications are working, so nothing unusual here. All of them have all accompanying files in the same folder.

And no, the one you CAN NOT move is the .config - because that is evaluated at start before your code can interfere.

I would say that unless you have some really good reason, you bark up a tree that is totally wrong. One good reason is dynamically loading assemblies i.e. based on parameters at start.

Comment: Is there a way then for me to embed the DLLs inside of the executable? Or maybe a way to not generate the .exe.config file?

Comment: Well, the .exe.config can be ignored if none of the settings there are relevant. Embedding? Sure, LEARN YOUR TOOLS. Single File is a .NET Core 3.0 and onward feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: Alright, will do. Thanks!